# Extended Properties in Microsoft Enterprise Logging

Tags: c#, logging, enterprise-library

Is there any way to change the format of Extended Properties in Microsoft Enterprise Logging in case if the value is of List or an array such that the count will be displayed

Currently i am using this and passing the count manually

```
dictionary.Add(" Employee(Count)", EmpList.Count());
```

and in the web config i am using like this

```
Extended Properties : {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}
```

So is there any way that i can make the format generic such that it will display the actual content if its a normal string or int and display the count if it is an array or list kind of input

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to achieve what you want is to create a custom formatter.  You could reuse almost all of the existing [`TextFormatter`](https://lab.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#source/Src/Logging/Formatters/TextFormatter.cs) implementation but change the implementation from calling the `GenericTextFormatter<>`:

```
GenericTextFormatter<KeyValuePair<string, object>> entryFormatter
            = new GenericTextFormatter<KeyValuePair<string, object>>(parameter, handlers);
```

to call your own custom implementation which would either perform a `ToString()` or a `Count()` depending on the object type.